# Is it possible to upload file in mysql database table by JMeter?

Tags: mysql, jmeter

I am new JMeter user.I already know how to use jmeter for testing.Now my question is,Is it possible to upload file in mysql table by JMeter?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm correctly getting your use case - you need to insert a file into MySQL BLOB or CLOB field. It's doable via JMeter.

**Option 1:**

Have you tried `Prepared Update Statement` option of JMeter [JDBC Request Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request)? It should be able to do the trick for you.

**Option 2**

If you need more flexibility JMeter can be [extended via Beanshell](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell). All you need is to drop [MySQL JDBC Connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) and drop it anywhere in JMeter classpath (usually it's /lib/ext folder for extension jars).

Once done you can establish MySQL connection and insert your file into MySQL database. Example code is below:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://host:port/databasename?user=databaseuser&password=databasepassword");
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(id, blob_col) VALUES(1, LOAD_FILE('/full/path/to/file/myfile.png')");
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
connect.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

using JMeter you can upload file into a website that have mysql back end. If you are thinking of direct file insert in mysql using JMeter I dont think that is possible.

Comment: Are you sure is it impossible directly file insert in mysql by JMeter?

Comment: I am quite sure that Jmeter by default does not provide that because its a performance testing tool of the application not database. But you can probabley use some jmeter listeners to insert data in database. But not very sure on that part. Pls check this, might help - http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/jmeter-user/201205.mbox/%3CBLU0-SMTP232133A6A173952A63D42B6E91E0@phx.gbl%3E