# JMeter JDBC stored Procedure invocation with BLOB parameter

Tags: jdbc, jmeter, db2

For testing purpose I need to invoke a DB2 Stored Procedure via JMeter.

I set up a **JDBC connection**, then add the **JDBC Request** step, but I have problem when populating the parameters.

The problem is that one of the parameters is a BLOB taken from a .bin file, and I can't find a way to insert it. The parameter are read from a CSV file.

What I did was:

```
Query Type: Callable statement
CALL MY.STOREDPROCEDURE(?,?,?)

Parameter values: ${par1},FROM_FILE('${par2}'),'a'
Parameter types: IN VARCHAR, INOUT BLOB, OUT VARCHAR
```

The error I get is that it can't convert String to Blob (

> Illegal conversion: can not convert from "java.lang.String" to
>   "java.sql.Blob" ERRORCODE=-4474 SQLSTAT=null.).

I think that the problem is that the FROM_FILE function return a String with the content of the file. 
Following an idea I found on-line I set up a **JSR233 Sampler** to load the file with a Groovy script, I saved the file as an Object, but when i read it it still seems to be read as a String, even with a groovy script (${__groovy()}).

I tried to do add a cast in the invocation but then I will get an error about the  "Literal replacement parsing failed for procedure call".

How can I pass a Blob to the invocation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to upload file in mysql database table by JMeter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20865762/is-it-possible-to-upload-file-in-mysql-database-table-by-jmeter)

Comment: @Randomguy, what did you mean by "saved the file as an Object"? Saved where?

Comment: @YuriG, What I meant is that I tried to save the Blob, obtained from the byte array read from the file, in the vars variable calling vars.putObject("blob", blobVariable). But when I try to read from it (vars.getObject("blob") it will still talk about the String error. I will update the question to explain better.

Comment: Gotcha. Did you try to do a type conversion explicitly in your __groovy() snippet?

Comment: Yes, I tried to create a new Blob object (SerialBlob) from the data I stored in the vars map. Still error on strings.
Right now I'm using a JSR223 sampler with some code to make the invocation, but I would still like to use the JDBC request...